# Submitting form twice using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rating-system

I am trying to submit the form using Ajax, but it submitted the entered values twice. Could you please help me to prevent this issue? I tried several suggestions from the previous questions, but it did not work.

Thank you

Html Code:

```
<form id="ratingForm" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Rate this product</h4>
        <!-- Start Star -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- End Star -->

        <input type="hidden"  id="rating" name="rating" value="1">
        <input type="hidden"  id="itemId" name="itemId" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="saveRating">
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--Comment Start-->
        <label for="usr">Title*</label>
        <input type="text"  id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment*</label>
        <textarea rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="saveReview">Save Review</button>
    </div>
     <!--Comment End-->          
</form>
```

Js Code:

```
$('#ratingForm').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: "json",   
        url : 'action.php',                 
        data : formData,
        success:function(response){
            if(response.success == 1) {
                $("#ratingForm")[0].reset();
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Php Code (This is action.php file):
Execution.php file  inserts data into database using mysql.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'class/Execution.php';
$rating = new Rating();

if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'saveRating'  
    && !empty($_POST['rating']) 
    && !empty($_POST['itemId'])) {
        $rating->saveRating($_POST, $_SESSION['userId']);   
        $data = array(
            "success"   => 1,   
        );
        echo json_encode($data);        
}

?>
```

Comment: can you give your html form and php code, so i can generate same error on my machine

Comment: I think there is some js error in your code , otherwise everything is perfect from your side.  Please add your html code also please for debugging more...

Comment: It's difficult to help you if we don't see the whole code for what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Ajith I've updated the post.

Comment: @TMN You can try the answer given by Akshay...Also make sure there is no js error on the page

Comment: @Ajith I did but it did not work. Also, there is no JS error :(

Comment: @TMN I have added an answer which does works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Js Check</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="ratingForm" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Rate this product</h4>
      <!-- Start Star -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButton" aria-label="Left Align"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      <!-- End Star -->
      
      <input type="hidden"  id="rating" name="rating" value="1">
      <input type="hidden"  id="itemId" name="itemId" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="saveRating">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
      <!--Comment Start-->
      <label for="usr">Title*</label>
      <input type="text"  id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment*</label>
      <textarea rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="saveReview">Save Review</button>
    </div>
    <!--Comment End-->
  </form>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        
        $('#ratingForm').on('submit', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: "json",   
                url : 'action.php',                 
                data : formData,
                success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                    if(response.success == 1) {
                        $("#ratingForm")[0].reset();
                        window.location.reload();
                    } 
                }
            }); 
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works. Could you please explain where is the error?

Comment: @TMN Make sure you ajax call script is added below your jquery include

Answer (score 2):

with the POST method your form may be submitting second time when it reload with `window.location.reload();` you can simply `redirect` the page when ajax call successfully with `window.location.href = "http://yourwebpage.php";` or `window.location.replace("http://yourwebpage.php");`

Comment: I have done this before, but unfortunately it didn't work